# Summary function error not from the body of that generic function

Tags: r, function, summary, nlme

I am trying to call the summary function of a model created by the lme function in the nlme package. code and data below.

It comes up with the follwing error
"call to standardGeneric("summary") apparently not from the body of that generic function"

```
diss <- read.csv("C:/Users/bikash.deb/Desktop/Will's Diss.csv")
library(nlme)
time <- factor(diss$protocol)
lmeforce <- lme(force ~ diss$time, data=diss, random = ~ 1|repeatedmeasure)
summary(lmeforce)

repeatedmeasure    protocol    force
freddie1           1           1500
freddie2           1           1600
ben1               1           1100
ben2               1           1200
```

appreciate the help

cheers,

Bikash

Comment: I don't understand why you call summary on the anova table. Can you add the exact error message after the line that throws it?

Comment: Hi Roland, it gives the same error message after both uses of summary() -"call to standardGeneric("summary") apparently not from the body of that generic function"

Comment: Is this in a fresh R session?

Comment: It wasn't. Just tried that and cleared the objects in the environment and is now working. thanks Roland